# How does AsyncTask method doInBackground() know when to finish?

Tags: android

I have a `HttpPostAsyncTask` class that extends `AsyncTask` that I'm using to send data to my express server and getting a response from it. Now, although the response is returned and I am returning the response as a String, the `doInBackground()` method does not finish and hence the `AsyncTask` is still running.

My `doInBackground()` method looks like this:

```
URL url = new URL(params[0]);
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.connect();

int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
switch (statusCode) {
  case 400:
    return "Error 400 - Bad request.";
  case 401:
    return "Error 401 - Unauthorized request.";
}
```

Now, when I log the `statusCode`, I am getting it correct. But the `doInBackground()` method doesn't end, and hence the task is still running.

I have searched a lot of places on the internet but am unable to find what exactly triggers the `doInBackground` method to end? If that ends, I suppose the AsyncTask shall end too, and I can receive the result in `onPostExecute()` method.

**Edit 1:**
So I have an Activity A that calls `startActivityForResult` twice. First, I have a `GoogleSignInIntent` and I am calling `startActivityForResult` for that. If it returns its results correctly, I am calling `startActivityForResult` again (with a different `requestCode` obviously). Now, I have followed [this article](https://medium.com/@lewisjkl/android-httpurlconnection-with-asynctask-tutorial-7ce5bf0245cd) and implemented a CustomCallback for all `statusCode`s in the `doInBackground()` method. I am also returning a value at the end of `doInBackground()`.

So the GoogleSignInIntent is correctly returning results and I start the next intent, for which my server returns proper response code and I call the custom callback handler as well as return a String from my `doInBackground()`. Still, the `onPostExecute()` is not called.

Comment: Can you include the full code for your doInBackground method?  Could an exception be happening?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you give it a look now after my edit?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to notice that you need to declare Inner classes as statics as they do not hold a reference to the activity to avoid memory leaks. And you also need to cancel your asynctask when your activity has finished (e.g. onDestroy() method). To know more about this topic check this medium article [Everything You Need To Know About Memory Leaks In Android Apps](https://blog.aritraroy.in/everything-you-need-to-know-about-memory-leaks-in-android-apps-655f191ca859).

```
private AsyncTask mHttpPostAsyncTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mHttpPostAsyncTask = new HttpPostAsyncTask().execute();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mHttpPostAsyncTask != null) {
        mHttpPostAsyncTask.cancel(true);
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                Inner Classes
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
private static class HttpPostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        switch (statusCode) {
            case 400:
                return "Error 400 - Bad request.";
            case 401:
                return "Error 401 - Unauthorized request.";
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        // doInBackground() has finished. Do something with your string.
        // Remember to check that it isn't null to avoid NPE.
        if (s != null) {
            // do something with the result.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The doInBackground() method ends when a value is returned, like any method that returns a value, the code that you show has a switch statement that shows 2 returning possibilities, if those values aren’t met then the method will not finish or might return a null value (I’m not 100% sure), so just add a

```
default:{}return null;
```

To the end of your switch statement to ensure it returns a value

Answer (score 0):

If `onPostExecute()` is being called then `doInBackground()` has completed.  `onPostExecute()` is called by the return value that you specify in `doInBackground()`.

Try assigning a `String` variable with a default value before the `switch` statement.  This variable can be set by each `case` or remain as the default if neither case is true.  Then return this variable at the end of the method.  That way you guarantee providing a return value to pass to `onPostExecute()`

```
URL url = new URL(params[0]);
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.connect();

int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
String returnCode = "";
switch (statusCode) {
  case 400:
    returnCode = "Error 400 - Bad request.";
  case 401:
    returnCode = "Error 401 - Unauthorized request.";
}
return returnCode;
```